# GAE - How to get last modified / renamed datetime of google cloud storage object from php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm modifying an existing mail spooling script (SwiftMailer) to work on GAE using GCS for storing the spooled files.

Part of the script uses PHP's filectime function to see when the file was last renamed, which doesn't seem to work with GAE's file wrapper for GCS. The python API has an option to get the last modified date of a file and I've seen a Java api example for getting the last modified date time but  can't find any equivalent in the PHP SDK as CloudStorageTools::getMetaData only seems to return custom metadata. I'm also not entirely clear if CGS would treat a rename as a modification or not?

Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filemtime.

```
>>> print_r(filemtime('gs://test/a_test_file.txt'));
1371084050
```

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have gone trying other file functions before asking!